# How to expose ALL properties of a Control in a class derived from Form?

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I have class derived from `Form` and it contains a `TableLayoutPanel` and in it one `Label` and one `Panel`. When I create instance of this Form, all properties and events of controls in design editor are read-only. Is there any way how to expose whole object for editing? I know that I can expose properties one by one, but that is not the best way in case when you want all of them.

Comment: *"I have UserControl derived from Form"* You really have a `public class Usercontrol : Form`? Are you dropping this on another form, or are you using it as a stand-alone form? Can you show how you declared the properties and events? Are the table layout panel and label, etc marked as `public` accessibility?

Comment: The controls like Label or Panel will be private so they will not be visible in inherited class.

Comment: I am using it as a stand-alone form in my MDI Parent form. And yes, all controls are public.

Comment: @MilanFornůsek If you have a form, and not a user control, then you should make that clear in your question, rather than saying  you have a user control when you have a form.

Comment: A form should not be exposing it's private controls like this.  The whole idea of having this class to to encapsulate access to those controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/best-practices-for-the-tablelayoutpanel-control):

> Avoid Visual Inheritance
>
> The `TableLayoutPanel` control does not support visual inheritance in
>   the `Windows Forms Designer`. A `TableLayoutPanel` control in a
>   derived class appears as *locked* at design time.

Comment: Thank you, that was the cause of the problem. After I removed TableLayoutPanel and keep only Label and Panel all is working now.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `internal` or make a getter method / property

```
public Label GetLabel() => return someLabel;
```

or

```
public Label MyLabel { get { return someLabel; } }
```

or

```
internal Label someLabel;
```